# Let $a_n=\frac {1}{3^n}$ if $n$ is prime and $a_n=\frac {1}{4^n}$ if $n$ is not prime.

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

Let $a_n=\frac {1}{3^n}$ if $n$ is prime  and $a_n=\frac {1}{4^n}$ if $n$ is not prime. Then I have to find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$ ?

I know that for the power series, $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$$ the radius of convergence is given by $R$ such that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left \vert a_n \right \vert^{1/n} R = 1$$ i.e. $$R = \dfrac1{\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left \vert a_n \right \vert^{1/n}}$$. Now I have two different values of $a_n$ depending on whether $n$ is prime or not prime. Now, if  $n$ is prime then $R=3$ and otherwise   $R=4$.

**EDIT:** Now as @Pambos has suggested that "Note that  $\limsup x_k$ is the $\sup$ of the set of limit points of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$.
".So I guess that the required radius of convergence of the given series is $4$.Am I going in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to use that formula?

Comment: I have two different values of $a_n$ depending on whether $n$ is prime or not prime. Now, if  $n$ is prime then $R=3$ and otherwise   $R=4$.

Comment: $R$ should be $3$.

Comment: The linit points of $\sqrt[n](a_n)$ are $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\dfrac{1}{4}$. Therefore $\limsup \sqrt[n](a_n)=\sup\left\{\dfrac13,\dfrac14\right\}\ldots$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.It is clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to calculate $\limsup x_k$ of a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$.

Note that  $\limsup x_k$ is the $\sup$ of the set of limit points of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$. Also if you partition $\mathbb N$ as $S_1\cup S_2$ (in your case *primes* $\cup$ *nonprimes*) the set of limit points of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is limit points of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb s_1} \cup$ limit points of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb s_2}$.

Comment: So I guess that the required radius of convergence of the given series is $4$.Am I right?

Comment: Last time I checked, $1/3\gt 1/4$

Comment: Since limsup $|a_n|^{1/n}=1/3$ as $1/3 >1/4$ and hence radius of convergence of the series is $3.$ Am I right sir?

Comment: Yes sir, you are right!